# Error al mandar arreglo a SQL Server desde aspx c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Buen día, estoy tratando de enviar el arreglo sn a SQL SERVER pero me sale el error

> The parameterized query '(@Serial_Number nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO Auditorias (Serial_Nu' expects the parameter '@Serial_Number', which was not supplied.

Adjunto el código, se manda cuando se hace clic en el botón "Approve":

```
public partial class Audit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<string> Serial_Number = new List<string>();
    List<string> User_SSO = new List<string>();
    List<string> User_Name = new List<string>();
    string[] sn = new string[5];
    string[] sso = new string[5];
    string[] user = new string[5];

    int i = 0;
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITTESTDBConnectionString"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 5 Brand, Model, Service_Tag, Hostname, User_SSO, User_Name, Memory, HD, OS FROM Laptops ORDER BY NEWID()";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            table.Append("<table border='1'>");
            table.Append("<tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th><th>Service Tag</th><th>Hostname</th><th>User SSO</th><th>User Name</th><th>Memory</th><th>HDD</th><th>Operative System</th>");
            table.Append("</tr>");

            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    table.Append("<tr>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[0] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[1] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[2] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[3] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[4] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[5] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[6] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[7] + "</td>");
                    table.Append("<td>" + rd[8] + "</td>");
                    Serial_Number.Add(rd[2].ToString());
                }
            }

            string[] sn = Serial_Number.ToArray();
            table.Append("</table>");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
            rd.Close();
        }
    }


    public void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITTESTDBConnectionString"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Auditorias (Serial_Number, Estado) VALUES (@Serial_Number,'Correcto')";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial_Number", sn[i]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que estas en un ambiente `web`, por lo tanto los valores de las variables no se conservan porque no hay estado entre cada request, para eso existe el objeto `Session`

Analiza algo como esto:

```
public partial class Audit : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Serial_Number = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            sting connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITTESTDBConnectionString"].ToString();
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                con.Open();

                string query = @"SELECT TOP 5 Brand, Model, Service_Tag, Hostname, User_SSO, User_Name, Memory, HD, OS 
                                FROM Laptops ORDER BY NEWID()";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                table.Append("<table border='1'>");
                table.Append("<tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th><th>Service Tag</th><th>Hostname</th><th>User SSO</th><th>User Name</th><th>Memory</th><th>HDD</th><th>Operative System</th>");
                table.Append("</tr>");

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        table.Append("<tr>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[0] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[1] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[2] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[3] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[4] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[5] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[6] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[7] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + rd[8] + "</td>");
                        Serial_Number.Add(rd[2].ToString());
                    }
                }

                table.Append("</table>");

                Session["Serial_Number"] = Serial_Number;

                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
           }
        }
    }


    public void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> serialNumber = (List<string>)Session["Serial_Number"];

        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITTESTDBConnectionString"].ToString();
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "INSERT INTO Auditorias (Serial_Number, Estado) VALUES (@SerialNumber, 'Correcto')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            foreach(var sn in serialNumber)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", sn);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Veras como uso:

```
Session["Serial_Number"] = Serial_Number;
```

para conservar la lista de serial number entre request, para después poder recuperarla

```
List<string> serialNumber = (List<string>)Session["Serial_Number"];
```

iterando los valores que serán pasado en el parámetro del insert

Comment: Eres un crack amigo, muchas gracias, habia pasado por alto el hecho de que no se conservan los valores